# Trouble with openxlsx

Tags: r, xlsx

When I attempt to load an xlsx file with the loadWorkbook function I receive an error message. I am loading the workbook file from my local working directory and receive the following error message:

> Error in grepl(target, commentsXML) : invalid 'pattern' argument

when I execute the basic function: 
loadWorkbook("template.xlsx") -> wb

Comment: what happens with `wb  <-  loadWorkbook("template.xlsx")` ?

Comment: If you look at the source code for `loadWorkbook`, you'll see that it uses `grepl` *dozens* of times, but fortunately only once with that signature. I suggest you try `trace("loadWorkbook", browser, at=64)` and step until the code populates `target`, and see what things look like at that stage. (It might help to know your OS, R, and package versions.) (My `at=64` is from `openxlsx-4.0.17`, and though 4.0.31 appears to be current on github, this function does not appear to have changed much this year.)

Comment: Thanks for your replies. When I use the trace function as specified above and then execute the same loadWorkbook("template.xlsx") -> wb, the following is returned to me: "Tracing loadWorkbook("template.xlsx") step 64  Called from: eval(expr, p)------ after browsing through Browse[1] output, the first instance where I see target is "Type=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2007/relationships/slicer\" Target=\"../slicers/slicer%s.xml\"/>", " 

My OS is Windows 7, 64bit, My R version is 3.4.2 (2017-09-28) and my package version is 4.0.17

Comment: Have you looked into readxl package? It is part of the tidyverse. I have never really liked any of the other excel packages like openxlsx, xlsx, etc.

Comment: I did look through the vignette for that package, but did not see the capability to write xlsx files in that package. Do you know if it is possible to write xlsx files using other packages that were previously read into r using the readxl package?

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks as if it's a bug. If you look at the source on github it has the following line:

```
hasComment <- sapply(drawXMLrelationship, length) > 0 ## which sheets have a drawing
```

However, it should be:

```
hasComment <- sapply(commentXMLrelationship, length) > 0
```