# unable to save with openxlsx package

Tags: r, xlsx

I have a large excel file and I am trying to load and save some data to. I did some tests and research and settled that I have to use `openxlsx`. `XLConnect` could not handle the size of the excel sheet and I tried various fixes.

Therefore I have written the below in `openxlsx` however getting an:

> Error in grepl(target, commentsXML) : invalid 'pattern' argument 
>   problem

I've tried `XLConnect`, but it doesn't work due to the size of the spreadsheet.

```
workbook <- openxlsx::loadWorkbook("excelsheet.xlsx")
writeData(workbook, "xxx", yyy, startCol = 1, startRow = 1)
saveWorkbook(workbook, file = "excelsheet.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

> Error in grepl(target, commentsXML) : invalid 'pattern' argument
>
> Error in "Workbook" %in% class(wb) : object 'workbook' not found
>
> Error in saveWorkbook(workbook, file = "xxx.xlsx", overwrite
>   = TRUE) :    unused argument (overwrite = TRUE)

Comment: may i ask why are you doing "I have a large excel file i am trying to load and save some data to"? cos after saving more data in that file, you might not be able to open it due to memory issue

Comment: i should be ok with openxlsx. I know XLconnect has memory issue. but i dont know what i am doing wrong, what is grepl??

Comment: They were saying this seems to be a bug [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47850646/trouble-with-openxlsx). I personally typically use `readxl` and `writexl`, but I've never tried huge files.

Comment: Thanks for showing me the bug. It seems odd that a bug sine Dec 2017 is still yet to be fixed?